# Validate Excel Data in C#

Tags: c#, excel, validation

I would like to validate Excel data according to the following before importing into a database:

1. Some columns have a maximum length
2. Some columns are numbers/dates
3. There must be no special characters

How can i go about this? (I am using C#)

EDIT: How do I validate an Excel column to have a maximum text length using Interop, for example, if I do not want the text to be more than 30 characters long? @JMK @artm @Linger @ivan_pozdeev @BenR

Comment: What library are you using? Or are you using interop? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you want to read excel data ? If so are you using some kind of API for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Microsoft OpenXML SDK for Office to open the file and examine its contents. Library is available here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Open XML SDK will be a great start

try this guide from MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg575571(v=office.15).aspx

NOTE - Open XML SDK is free to use and distribute. Go through documentation and first try to understand how Spreadsheets are structured. Also Open XMl SDK support ONLY open XMl file foramts, that means .XLSX as default for exel and NOT .XLS

Comment: I wen through the SDK but I'm still not sure how to go about it. How does the Open XML SDK compare to Interop?

Comment: Interop need MS Excel installed to operate.. Open XMl SDK doesn't need that. Open XMl allows you to create rich Excel file (.XLSX as default) :) Hopw you understood 

Note - Open XMl allows you to operate even at server side .!!!!!

Comment: Read - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/418ada31-8748-48d2-858b-d177326daa76/export-to-excel-open-xml-sdk-vs-microsoftofficeinteropexcel?forum=oxmlsdk

Comment: Additionally, OpenXML SDK does not require you to have a license for MS Office or any Office components installed as it operates at a file level, and the file format is public domain.